# AngularJs directive: value from cookie does not apply to data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created the directive, with the dropdown list of organizations the user is assigned to:

```
.directive('orgList', ['$rootScope', '$state', 'Auth', 'ipCookie', function ($rootScope, $state, Auth, ipCookie) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div class="form-group"><div class="input-group">'+ 
            '<span class="input-group-addon"><b>My orgs</b></span>'+
             '<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedOrg"'+
                  'ng-options="org.name for org in orgs"></select>'+
                '</div></div>',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
                scope.orgs = Auth.user.organizations;
                scope.selectedOrg = ipCookie('selectedOrg') || _.first(scope.orgs);

                scope.$watch('selectedOrg', function (value) {
                    if(!_(value).isEmpty()) {
                        ipCookie('selectedOrg', value);

                        var temp = { 
                            role: Auth.userRoles[value.role] || Auth.user.role 
                        }
                        _(Auth.user).extend(temp);
                        $rootScope.$broadcast('userRoleChanged', value.id);
                    }
                });

                scope.$on('userRoleChanged', function (event, id) {
                    if(!Auth.authorize(Auth.accessLevels.admin)) {
                        if($state.current.url.match('/organization/')) {
                            $state.go('private.profile');
                        }
                    } 
                });
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

Now I want to make it remember the user selection: when user choose the organization in dropdown, after page reload I want him see the same organization from cookie.

What is the problem:

```
scope.selectedOrg = ipCookie('selectedOrg') || _.first(scope.orgs);
```

if the cookie is not defined and the `_.first(scope.orgs)` part is selected, the dropdown show the organization as it should, but if I get the value from cookie, then it show empty dropdown text. `console.log()` show the selectedOrg to be correct in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most probable cause is object identity.

This means that the value retrieved from the `ipCookie()` service may have the same content as one from the `orgs` list (i.e. fields are the same, if compared one by one) but the object itself is *different* in the Javascript `a === b` sense. As it is, Angular is configured to use the JS equality comparison.

You can:

1. Try adding the `track by` clause:

   ```
   <select ... ng-options="org.name for org in orgs track by org.id">
   ```
2. If `ipCookie('selectedOrg')` returns a value, do not place it in `scope.selectedOrg`; instead search your `orgs` list for that specific object and place that object in `scope.selectedOrg`.

Comment: Works as a charm. Thank you.